# Can't find objects in ArrayList passed to server through GWT-RPC

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, collections, gwt-rpc

I have an `ArrayList` of `ShortcutVirtualSystemEntry` where :

```
public class ShortcutVirtualSystemEntry extends VirtualSystemEntry implements IsSerializable {

  public ShortcutVirtualSystemEntry(String id, String label, String image,
      String tooltip, String parent, int x, int y, int tray, Command action) {
    super(id, label, image, tooltip, parent, x, y, tray, action);
  }

public ShortcutVirtualSystemEntry() {

}

}
```

When I try to pass the `ArrayList` from client to server through `RPC` call all objects are of the List are instantiated but have no data 
here the RPC:

```
docService.saveDocument2(shortcuts,
                new AsyncCallback<Void>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                        Window.alert("Faliled");
                        caught.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void result) {
                        Window.alert("Success");

                    }
                });
```

Server side:

```
@Override
public void saveDocument2(
        List<ShortcutVirtualSystemEntry> shortcuts) {
    for(ShortcutVirtualSystemEntry v: shortcuts)
    {
        System.out.println("Image "+v.getImage());// Prints : Image null...
    }


}
```

So why do I have to lose my list data ? what I'm doing wrong

Thanks so much in advance :)

Comment: Is in your code Aysnc call returning list of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about GWT. But the common rule of RPC is to make sure that elements in collection are also serializable. So if you are sending list which is serializable but the objects in the list are not serializable then you will not get the elements correctly through RPC. So make sure the objects in the lists are seriablizable.

Comment: Although I knew that Info but for my stupidity I forget to make ``Command`` which is field of ``ShortcutVirtualSystemEntry `` Serializable

Answer (score 0):

As much as I can say, your code should work. Probably your problem is somewhere else, i.e. you forgot to set the Image in the constructor or you just don't set an Image.

What's important by GWT is, that the objets you send through RPC are Serilizable and often it also helps to create an empty Constructer for these objects.

Sarajog